# Find & replace for hostname in `~/.ssh/config` to run a different shell/`RemoteCommand` for a group of hosts?

Tags: ssh

I can ssh as normal into several hosts. I have sudo/su rights, so I often need to type that when I log into the server. Is there any way, in my `~/.ssh/config` to automate that?

I have

```
Host *.example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_projkey
```

I'd like `ssh blah.example.com` to still work as normal, where I get a regular shell. But then `ssh su-blah.example.com` to log me in, and then run `sudo -i` (or `su`), i.e. the equivalent of running `ssh blah.example.com -t sudo -i`. I see I can add `RemoteCommand` to the SSH config. Is there anyway to do a “pattern match” & text replace on the hostname in a SSH config?`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think one can do substitutions on hostnames in ssh_config, but I'd try to add a second entry with a leading dot, like:

```
Host *.example.com.
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_projkey
  RemoteCommand sudo -i
  RequestTTY yes
```

The DNS name with leading dot should be identical to DNS entries without dot, but ssh will see this as a different hostname

Alternatively, you could add entries which override the hostname, but then you'd need one for each host. eg.:

```
host su-foo.example.com
  hostname foo.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_projkey
  RemoteCommand sudo -i
  RequestTTY yes
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or similar are probably the tools you are looking for here.